# What is the difference between execute, test and capture commands in Capistrano?

Tags: ruby, capistrano, sshkit

On [SSHkit-Github](https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit) it's says:

> All backends support the execute(*args), test(*args) & capture(*args)

From [SSHkit-Rubydoc](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/sshkit/1.7.1/SSHKit/Backend/Printer#capture-instance_method), I understand that `execute` is actually an alias to `test`?

What is the difference between `test`, `execute`, `capture` in **Capistrano**/**SSHKit** and when should I use either?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**execute**
just executes command. 
raises error with non-`0` exit.

**test** 
method behaves exactly the same as `execute` however it returns boolean (`true` if command exits with a `0` exit, and `false` otherwise). it'll usually be used for control flow in your tasks.

**capture**
method will execute the command on the first matching server, and will return the `stdout` output of the command as a string. `stderr` output will be ignored (use `ls 2>&1` to redirect stderr to stdout). 
raises error with non-`0` exit.